# Eigenvalues of Certain Symmetric Block Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What can we say about the relation between the eigenvalues of the following block matrix with identity diagonal blocks, and the singular values of the off-diagonal blocks:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma=\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
  I_{k\times k} & B_{k\times n-k} \\
  B_{n-k\times k}^{T} & I_{n-k\times n-k} \\
  \end{array} } \right)
\end{equation}

We know (also from my other questions) that if the blocks are all of the same size (\frac{n}{2}) then we have:
$$\lambda_{i}(\Gamma)^{\pm}=1\pm\sigma_{i}(B)$$. What about the general case where the sizes are not equal. Consider for the sake of clarity $0\leq k\leq \frac{n}{2}$. I believe $k$ of them are equal to unity.

Comment: The answer will ultimately be "kind of the same, but with extra zeros depending on how you define singular values".  So, here's a question: if $B$ is $m \times n$, then how many singular values does $B$ have when $m < n$?  What about if $m > n$?  With the definition that I'm used to, $B$ always has $n$ singular values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helpful start.  Suppose first that $k < n/2$.  The SVD then gives us
$$
B = U\pmatrix{\Sigma & 0}V^*
$$
where $\Sigma$ is square an diagonal, and $0$ is a block matrix of $0$s.

Define 
$$
\tilde U = \pmatrix{U\\& V}
$$
We then have
$$
\tilde U^* \Gamma \tilde U = 
\pmatrix{
I & \Sigma & 0\\ 
\Sigma & I & 0\\
0 & 0 & I}
$$
As you can verify by block-matrix multiplication.

Similarly, when $k > n/2$ and defining $\tilde U$ as above, you end up with
$$
\tilde U^* \Gamma \tilde U = 
\pmatrix{
I & 0 & \Sigma \\ 
0 & I & 0\\
\Sigma & 0 & I}
$$
In either case, the answer is something like "you get a few extra $1$s as eigenvalues".

---

My full answer for your case would be as follows: when $k < n/2$, $B$ has $k$ singular values.  We then get $n - 2k$ additional eigenvalues of $\Gamma$ in addition to those determined by the singular values, and each additional eigenvalue is unity.